# When should we change the IFS variable back to its original value in scripts?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, scripting, ifs

Let's say I execute this script via a cronjob:

```
IFS=$'\n'

for i in `cat "$1"`; do
    echo "$i" >> xtempfile.tmp;
done
```

It works fine without causing any issues. But when I run this in a terminal, I have to set `IFS` variable back to its original value

```
IFS=$OLDIFS
```

Generally in which cases should we have to set `IFS` back to its original value?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of:

```
IFS=$'\n'

for i in `cat "$1"`; do
    echo "$i" >> xtempfile.tmp;
done
```

You can do something like:

```
while IFS=$'\n' read -r line; do
echo "$line"
done < "$1" >> xtempfile.tmp
```

This would set the `IFS` variable for the duration of `while loop`.

*Addition based on samveen's comments. Anytime a change is made to `IFS` in a subshell, the changes are reverted automatically. However, that is not true when you made modifications in interactive shell. The above suggestion is the required handling done to ensure we don't accidentally modify the `IFS` for the entire shell. *

Comment: Indeed efficient, but can you tell me generally in which cases we have to set IFS back to its original value? For example when the script is used in terminals? Is it a good practice to always set it back (or changing it for use only in specific scopes)?

Comment: `IFS` is used by bash as a splitting mechanism. So a good practice would be to set it to your needs only for the duration of your requirement and then set it back. Default value of `IFS` is `space, tabs and newline`. This [answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/18886/11209) will shed some more light.

Comment: @VassilisGr To add to this answer, in your examples in the question, the change in `IFS` in the `cron` job is a local change for the duration of the script's run, and a change in `IFS` in the interactive shell is a local change for the duration of the shell. There are no changes to the `IFS` value for other shells or cron jobs.

Comment: @JS웃 could you add the fact that a change in the `IFS` variable's value is a local change for just the duration of the cron job/shell and children, and doesn't affect the system as a whole.

Comment: cron uses a seperate shell for each job so IFS is only changed within your job, as JS said you should change it back just after you're done

Comment: @Samveen True, I missed adding that part. Have added to the answer for brevity.

Comment: @JS웃 Upvoted. The IFS for the interactive shell is for the duration of just the interactive shell. It seems that VassilisGr doesn't understand that these changes are local to the current shell and children in every case, whether interactive or non-interactive.

Comment: Unless you are concerned about preserving leading and trailing whitespace, there is no need to change the value of `IFS` once you switch to using `read`. You are reading the line into a single variable, no word splitting is performed.